# How to adjust empty cell in grid layout in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-gridlayout, adjustable

I am working on android project using kotlin and xml. I have design a screen in where there are six menu like below
[image: initial view]

When I set visibility gone to the menu named "Chuti". Then the screen look likes below..
[image: Problematic view]

But my expected screen will be look like..
[image: my expected screen]

Here the activity file:

```
 class ChutiActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private lateinit var binding : ActivityChutiBinding
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityChutiBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.chutiTV.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

you must remove the item and notifidatasetChange() your adapter. Add the below code to your adapter :

```
   YourModel item = getItem(position);  
   if(position == your_remove_item_index){   
     remove(item);
   }
`
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I haven't fetched the menu using recyclerview. The has come from xml code.

Comment: Can I see your XML code? 
Do you use a constant layout?

Comment: Here is the code in the below link..

https://bdsevencircle-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/habibur_r_sevenringscement_com/Ef08Cs3lfzhCrgjR14m0dZQBFpz7TPMCbX18gN4WVcznDA?e=zQ53j2

Comment: Use 'gridLayout.removeView(chutiTV)' to remove items and use gridLayout.addView(chutiTV , index) for add items.